# System.Load(<mysharedLibName>) : SIGABRT

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, java-native-interface

Why I am getting SIGABRT whenever I am trying to load the native library.
I have already enabled the Hybrid debugging and given the path to the Symbols to \libs\armeabi in the Symbol Directories?

**UPDATE :** 
Project structure is like this : 
P1-> calls aar(P2)
aar library internally calls the native library(P3).

I have sources of all P1,P2 and the native code (P3)

Comment: Check your logs. quite possible the error is not related to loading the lib but is a good ol' coding error

Comment: does it happen only when debugging?

Comment: Yes Only in debugging.Release works fine.I am wondering if there is any other setting.There is some more information I am adding to the Question.Please check in a while.

Comment: does `ndk-stack` explain anything?

Comment: how can I run ndk-stack ?Btw the ndk I am using is not one from the sdk manager but from the ndk download link on android site.Does experimental gradle plugin play any role?

Comment: i am using ndk the same way, its working